# Open Office.org: Change Default Options on new installations

Tags: automation, openoffice

I am migrating workstations in my office from MS Office to Open Office 3.2. Thankfully the migration has been painless till now.
After I install Open Office, I change the default Load / Save options under **Tools>Options>Load/Save>General**
to save in Microsoft Office compatible formats (97/2000/XP) and I unselect the Warn when not saving in ODF or default format.
I have to do this for a number of Workstations in my Office manually, which takes entire days.
And if I forget to change the settings on one workstation, I get complaints that the file is being saved to an unknown format. Most of our contacts still use Office 2003 and do not support the OOo default document formats.

My question: Is there an easier way to change settings after installation without manually changing them, like running a *.reg file after the install or creating an unattended installation which includes changing the settings?

Unattended installation: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Automatic_Installation_on_Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to record the steps you use to change the settings using [EZ Macros](http://www.americansys.com/ezmacros.htm), and then play the macro back on the computer with the new installation.

You can record both keyboard shortcuts and mouse movements and clicks. For more reliable results, use keyboard shortcuts only, because mouse positions may not remain the same on different computers.

EZ Macros allows you to package the recording as an executable, so you won't need to worry about installing EZ Macros itself on your target computers.

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer. i appreciate it. i was looking for a setup which could be run in the background when the workstation is in use.

Comment: While EZ Macros may not be able to do that in the background, you can set the playback speed to be faster. Also, you can customize the recording script so that unnecessary waiting is reduced. For example, you can send keystrokes as soon as a particular window or dialog box appears on the screen, without any delay.

Comment: I have used EZ Macros before, but is not the ideal solution for workstations under use and for workstations of different resolutions. accepted as answer for lack of another answer.